# Why would casting a vararg function parameter matter?

Tags: c++, casting, variadic-functions

Recently I've encountered a problem with a function that accepts variable number of arguments and expects the last one to be a null pointer. *I don't have access to its implementation.*

Casting that last parameter to a `void*` worked, but passing in `NULL` (`nullptr` not available) directly wouldn't:

```
foo(x,y,(void*)NULL);   //okay
foo(x,y,NULL);          //crash
```

IMO this shouldn't make a difference, but then again, I've been wrong before. Can you think of any reason the cast would make a difference? or is this simply an accident (some desync or faulty build or smth. along those lines)

Sorry in advance that I can't provide more details.

Comment: Because `NULL` is an integer and `(void*)NULL` is a pointer? varargs won't convert anything like normal functions would.

Comment: @Pubby I just can't see how that would matter inside the function. Can you provide an example?

Comment: I think this is the problem, use nullptr instead and it should work

Comment: *"expects the last one to be a null pointer"*, does the interface documentation say anything about this parameter?

Comment: @Felics it works with the cast, I want to know *why*.

Comment: @AlokSave the interface, no, the docs, yes (null pointer).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, `NULL` is an integral constant in C++, whereas `(void *)NULL` is very definitely a pointer type.

So they could conceivably have different sizes when inserted into the var-arg list.  So this would certainly make a difference if, say, there's another parameter following it.  And if there isn't, you may end up reading half-garbage from inside the var-arg function.

Answer (score 2):

When you are using variable numbers of arguments (a variadic function), the way the stack gets built follows type-based rules for building the stack. But the called function doesn't know, for sure, what's really on the stack. It just has to make assumptions and go on. That's why passing the wrong arguments to a printf is so dangerous - if you've told it to expect a long int, and you only give it a short int, it's going to read more data from the stack than you put on, and bad things will happen.

For your problem, integers may not be pointer sized on your architecture. (That is to say, sizeof(int) != sizeof(void*)). Since the NULL is getting pushed onto the stack as an integer, if it's not pointer sized, then when the function pulls a 'pointer' off the stack, it's grabbing who knows what.

Integers may end up in registers, while pointers end up on the stack, or perhaps a different register file. I've never seen this in variadic functions, but I suspect at least some compilers & architectures could do it. In this case, the called function is looking in the wrong place for the data, and again, nothing good comes from it.

Answer (score 1):

`NULL` is a null pointer constant, so must be "*an integral constant expression prvalue of integer type that evaluates to zero or a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`.*"  If `nullptr` isn't available we can assume that it is a zero-valued integer constant prvalue e.g. `0`.  The failure indicates that the varargs calling semantics are different for `void *` arguments and those of the (promoted) type of `NULL`, e.g. if pointers are 64-bit and `int` is 32-bit.